# (Xamarin iOS): ExecutionEngineException - Attempting to JIT compile method while running in aot-only mode

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

When running app in release mode on device I am getting error:
ExecutionEngineException - Attempting to JIT compile method ‘AudioJack.ACRAudioJackReader:.ctor (bool)’ while running in aot-only mode. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/ for more information.

It appeared after latest update of Xamarin iOS.
Works OK on device in debug mode.
Also tried to disable compiler optimizations - didn't help.

I am using iOS binding to AudioJack library and the constructor is causing error.

```
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface ACRAudioJackReader
{

    [ExportAttribute("initWithMute:")]
    IntPtr Constructor(bool isMute);
}
```

Checked all the articles related to this issue, but didn't find solution yet.

Does anybody have an idea how it can be fixed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

You need to turn on *Enable optimizations* option in the problematic binding project.

---

I had similar issue to yours.

I work on Mac and switched from *Xamarin Studio* to the newest *Visual Studio for Mac*. After update app stoped working on iOS devices but, what’s interesting, simulators were fine.

The error occurred during the runtime when I wanted to initialize objects form this problematic library. My app has few iOS bindings projects but only one caused such problems. I didn’t want to introduce any unnecessary changes into the other projects.

Finally I found out that in my case it is enough to turn on *Enable optimizations* for the binding project which include this problematic library. The app’s project (which is the only project which use this library) hasn't been changed.

Because I knew that my app was working just before the update, I assumed that this was a *Xamarin* problem, so I focused only on finding a solution, not a reason.

---

You can find this option in:

**Project Options** > **Build** > **Compiler** > **Enable optimizations**

[image: Screenshot for Enable optimizations in Visual Studio for Mac]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been filed as a bug and is supposed to be fixed in a release next week.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56962